# Where does my First Responder Chain start?

Tags: objective-c, first-responder, nsviewcontroller

I am in he final step to design my application. 
It Basically consists of two tableviews plus other views. Each TableView has its own TableViewController class instance. 
What I would like to do is to activate the corresponding menu items when the user clicks one of the table view row. For example, I want to delete the file the user is currently selecting, so the file menu save is activated. But if he is not in the table view, I want to gray it out in the menu.

Therefore, I want to use First Responder. I added menu item, defined an action delete: in the First Responder and linked the menu item to that action. TableViewController is a subclass of NSViewController. In The TableViewController.m, I write in the init method (to insert the view controller in the responder's chain):

```
    [self setView:_tableView];
    [self setNextResponder:self.view];
    [self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSView *subview, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { [subview setNextResponder:self]; }];
```

But My method delete: doesn't get called! When the user click the tableview, it becomes the First Responder right? Then THe ViewController should receive the action. 
Otherwise, What is the First Responder and how to set it?
I guess I'm missing something!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. I just forgot to add a semicolon to my actions when I defined them in the First Responder.

SO I entered "delete" instead of "delete: " And just for this reason, my method -(void)delete:(id)sender was not called!

Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

### reason it doesn't work

the firstResponder is the first view, or the window, or the app itself that responds to the selectors

basically

```
id firstResponder = keyView;
while(![firstResponder respondsToSelector:yourSelector] && firstResponder != nil) {
    firstResponder = firstResponder.superview;
}

if(!firstResponder && [keyView.window respondsToSelector:sel]) {
    firstResponder = window;
}

if(!firstResponder && [application respondsToSelector:sel]) {
    firstResponder = application;
}
```

ViewControllers are not in the responder chain and never get the selector

see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html

### solution

add the VC into the responder chain

```
id resp = myTableView.nextResponder;
myViewController.nextResponder = resp;
tableView.nextResponder = myViewController;
```

Comment: THank you for your answer. I know I have to include my ViewController in my responder's chain. My problem I think is : 1) I don't understand how is set the First Responder. 2) When the user click the first table view and press the delete key, I want to call the function delete from MyTableView class and when he clicks on an outline view, I want to call a delete method I would have implemented from this class. HOw can I do that?

Comment: Reread my post maybe. You DONT set the first responder. It is determined by OS X by walking along the responder chain -- I also showed you how to integrate your controller. :)

Comment: ok let me rephrase it is hard to explain what I don't understand. When I click on a view, does this view become first responder? If yes, I don't understand because even when I implement a method delete: in my view class, I linked menu item delete to delete: method in frist responder, then I run my application, I click on my view and the delete menu item is still grayed out. Why? Am I missing something?